# matriz serie limite 4

Tags: java

Mi matriz actualmente imprime:

> 1234
>
> 1234
>
> 1234
>
> 1234

Necesito que solamente se imprima de la siguiente forma:

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234

Mi código es este:

```
 Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
    int columnas;
    int filas;
    int i;
    int j;
    System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
    columnas =pedir.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
    filas =pedir.nextInt();
    int numPrimos[][] = new int [columnas][filas];

    for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
        int A ;
        for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
            numPrimos[i][j]=j;
            A = numPrimos[i][j];
        } 

    }

    for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
        for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
            System.out.print(numPrimos[i][j]);
        }System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que se busca es imprimir tantos carácteres como filas se han imprimido. Para conseguir esto lo haría modificando los límites de los bucles de la siguiente forma:

```js
    int columnas;
    int filas;
    int i;
    int j;
    //System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
    //columnas =pedir.nextInt();
    //System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
    //filas =pedir.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("4 Columnas y 4 filas");
    columnas = filas = 4;
    int numPrimos[][] = new int [columnas][filas];
    
    for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
        //int A ; <- Linea innecesaria
        //for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
        for(j = 0;(j <= i && j<numPrimos[i].length);j++){ // De esta forma rellenamos los elementos que nos interesan únicamente. Esto es opcional pero según mi opinión si no se va a trabajar con un objeto mejor no instanciarlo para optimizar el proceso.
            numPrimos[i][j]=j+1; // Se añade 1 para que lo que se muestre en pantalla empieze en 1 y no en 0.
            //A = numPrimos[i][j]; <- Linea innecesaria
        } 

    }

    for(i = 0;i<numPrimos.length;i++){
        // Esta es la línea de código que cambiaría para conseguir dicho resultado
        //for(j = 0;j <numPrimos.length;j++){
        for(j = 0;(j <= i && j<numPrimos[i].length);j++){ // Así conseguimos que se impriman solo los carácteres que necesitamos sin llegar al limite numPrimos[i].length
            System.out.print(numPrimos[i][j]);
        }System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Te comento los cambios. Primero se ha cambiado el primer bucle, para que solo almacene en la matriz los valores con los que se va a trabajar en este proceso. Antes, la matriz era de la siguiente forma:

```
[0][0] = 1    [1][0] = 1    [2][0] = 1    [3][0] = 1
[0][1] = 2    [1][1] = 2    [2][1] = 2    [3][1] = 2
[0][2] = 3    [1][2] = 3    [2][2] = 3    [3][2] = 3
[0][3] = 4    [1][3] = 4    [2][3] = 4    [3][3] = 4
```

Despues del cambio en el primer bucle, se nos queda la matríz así:

```
[0][0] = 1    [1][0] = 1    [2][0] = 1    [3][0] = 1
[0][1] unde.  [1][1] = 2    [2][1] = 2    [3][1] = 2
[0][2] unde.  [1][2] unde.  [2][2] = 3    [3][2] = 3
[0][3] unde.  [1][3] unde.  [2][3] unde.  [3][3] = 4
```

Por otro lado, el cambio en el segundo bucle evita que se den más vueltas de las necesarias a la hora de mostrar. Como te habrás percatado es la misma solución en ambos bucles, evitar que dé más vueltas de las que realmente necesita. En un ejemplo de 4 líneas no hay apenas diferencia, pero si el mismo código ejecutase millones de registros, la diferencia entre hacerlo de forma eficiente o no es mucho mayor.

Para que puedas hacer la prueba, te añado los resultados de haberlo hecho con la mejora de rendimiento y sin ella para una matriz de 400x400.

```
Sin mejora - 834ms.
Con mejora - 276ms.
```

Espero que te sirva para tener en cuenta todos los detalles cuando busques una solución, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema en el bucle que estás usando, para hacer correctamente lo que buscas deberías tenerlo de esta forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    string str = "";        

    //Sólo precisas de una pregunta de número.
    System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas y Filas");
    num = pedir.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++) //Recorremos las filas
    {
        str = ""; //Reseteamos la variable para no guardar el numero anterior
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) //Recorremos las columnas dependiendo del numero de fila donde estemos
        {
            str = str + j; //Construimos el numero para imprimirlo
        } 
        System.out.print(str + "\n"); //Sacamos el numero por pantalla
    }
}
```

Con este código obtienes el resultado esperado.

Si ponemos el número 4 obtendrás:

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 1234

Answer (score -2):

Ahora que he entendido tu pregunta, veo que es algo que podrías haberlo hecho fácilmente con el Debugging de tu IDE para saber qué valor tiene `i` y `j` para parar o seguir el guardado de valores en determinada posición. Con el uso de `if` lo he logrado rápidamente. He comentado las líneas para que puedas entenderlo.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Menu_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
        int columnas;
        int filas;

        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Filas");
        filas = pedir.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de Columnas");
        columnas = pedir.nextInt();

        int[][] numPrimos = new int[filas][columnas]; // Lo correcto es filas x columnas, no viceversa como lo tenías

        pedir.close(); // Cerrar Scanner

        for (int i = 0; i < numPrimos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numPrimos.length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 1) { // Guarda: 1
                    break;
                }

                if (i == 1 && j == 2) { // Guarda: 1 2
                    break;
                }

                if (i == 2 && j == 3) { // Guarda: 1 2 3
                    break;
                }

                numPrimos[i][j] = j + 1;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numPrimos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numPrimos.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(numPrimos[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 1000
>
> 1200
>
> 1230
>
> 1234